# codeigniter csrf not working in safari

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, csrf

I have used j query ajax function to send ajax requests. I am using codeigniter 2.1.4. I have also enabled CSRF. The problem is when I send ajax requests using POST method it does not work but works when type is changed to GET. But even if I change the type to GET, It does not redirect to correct page giving 302 error.

my code is like this.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>url_to_function/',
  data: some_data+"&<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>=<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>",
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response) {
    if ( response) {
      self.location.href  = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>url_to_function/';
    }
    else { 
      // error 
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You can try to remove url's last `/`

Comment: no luck for this one.

Comment: You can try it, `some_data + "&<?php echo ....?>";`, as string connect.

Comment: thats not the problem. things are working fine on other browsers.

Comment: I think you can check server log.

Comment: What browser is causing problems?

Comment: only safari, and only when ajax request is used with type POST.

Answer (score 0):

OK I have found the answer if someone is looking for it. CSRF does not work in safari when your app is running in an iframe. Safari by default block 3rd party cookies. So in order to create iframe apps there are two methods

1. create session-less single page apps
2. Create apps that are first redirected to your site so that they can create a session and then redirected back to source site.

Tictail uses the first one whereas shopify uses the second one.